# Adding a css class to a div on click

Tags: html, css

I have a main nav bar with different items, I do also have a collapsed one with the exact same items but once the collapsed one is open I want to add a css class to each item of the navbar and then re delete it once I close the nav. Any idea how can I do this ?

```
<ul>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="business">Business</a>
                        </li>
</ul>
```

I want to add class name nav-link-collapsed as an exemple once it's open

Comment: I think you're saying that you have two nav-bars; one is hidden and the other is visible. When you show the hidden nav-bar, you want to add classes to its children? Why, what do those classes do? How are you opening the collapsed nav-bar? When you say you want to "*delete it once I close the nav*" do you mean hide the nav-bar again, or remove those class-names? Can you share your "*[mcve]*" code so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: This class gonna simple add a padding-bottom for each item of the navbar. Yes I do mean the remove those class-names.

Comment: @DavidThomas I just share an exemple of the question

Comment: You can try adding `onclick="this.classList.toggle('nav-link-collapsed')"`. Just make sure you start with the class present/not-present as needed.

Comment: How is the collapsed nav-bar opened?

Comment: why add the class to every single item instead of just the container?

Comment: @DavidThomas it's not my code so I'm trying to analyse it.

Comment: @tacoshy Can you give me an exemple using the code bellow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created my own JS who does this for me :

When I open

```
  $(".navbar-toggler").on("click", function() {
    $(".collapse").toggleClass("show");
    $(".nav-item").toggleClass("collapsed-space")
    $(".navbar-close").show();
  });
```

When I close

```
  $(".navbar-close").on("click", function() {
    $(".collapse").toggleClass("show");
    $(".navbar-close").hide();
    $("body").toggleClass("layer-open");
    $(".nav-item").toggleClass("collapsed-space")
    // $(header).toggleClass("sticky-not");
    $(".dark-overlay").click(function() {
      $(".collapse").removeClass("show");
      $("body").removeClass("layer-open");
      $(".nav-item").removeClass("collapsed-space")
    });
  });
```